# How to access a serial device from VM Server

Tags: putty, vmware-workstation, serial-port, plink

I have a serial device that is physically connected to my Window PC. From my window, I can use "PUTTY" to set up the connection to access this device and do some extra work after login this device.

Now I have this device unplugged and have it connected to a VMWare workstation ( vSphere 6.7 is installed on that workstation). And I have just created a new VM machine create on this workstation.

Now my question is, what are the necessary setup steps, that I may eventually access the device from this VM?

Answer (score 1):

I have just found out the answer myself. The key part is this device is visible to any VMs on this work station.

On any VM machine ( mine is of UBUNTU), run this command:

```
dmesg | grep tty
[    1.151102] 00:05: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

This "ttyS0" is the entry of that device. So the rest connect part is the same as I did on Windows. I am also using putty/plink on it.